# String Length Winsock + UTF8 + "ç"

Tags: c#, ruby, utf-8, winsock

Actually I have a problem with "receive data" in server.

Everything works fine , here's what the server does with the data it receives:

```
    string data = null;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[40000];
    client.TCPClient.GetStream().Read(buffer, 0, 40000);
    data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
    Server.Network.ReceiveData.SelectPacket(client.Index, data);
```

Void:

```
public static void SelectPacket(int Index, string data)
{
    string[] packets = data.Split('\\');
    for (int i = 0; i < packets.Length; i++)
    {
        if (packets[i] == String.Empty) { break; }
        if (packets[i].StartsWith("<0>")) { ReceivedAuth(Index); }
        else if (packets[i].StartsWith("<1>")) { ReceivedDisconnect(Index); }
        else if (packets[i].StartsWith("<3>")) { ReceivedMotd(Index); }
        else if (packets[i].StartsWith("<4>")) { ReceivedLogin(Index, packets[i]); }
        else if (packets[i].StartsWith("<5>")) { ReceivedRegister(Index, packets[i]); }
        else if (packets[i].StartsWith("<6>")) { ReceivedNewChar(Index, packets[i]); }
        else if (packets[i].StartsWith("<7>")) { ReceivedLoadChar(Index, packets[i]); }
        else if (packets[i].StartsWith("<8>")) { ReceivedIngame(Index, packets[i]); }
        else if (packets[i].StartsWith("<10>")) { ReceivedUpdatePlayer(Index); }
        else if (packets[i].StartsWith("<11>")) { ReceivedMove(Index, packets[i]); }
        else if (packets[i].StartsWith("<12>")) { ReceivedMessage(Index, packets[i]); }
        else if (packets[i].StartsWith("<13>")) { ReceivedInvSlots(Index, packets[i]); }
        else if (packets[i].StartsWith("<14>")) { LatencyCheck(Index); }
        else if (packets[i].StartsWith("<15>")) { MapCheck(Index, packets[i]); }
        else if (packets[i].StartsWith("<16>")) { UseItemCheck(Index, packets[i]); }
        else if (packets[i].StartsWith("<17>")) { EquipItemCheck(Index, packets[i]); }
        else if (packets[i].StartsWith("<18>")) { AttackCheck(Index, packets[i]); }
        else if (packets[i].StartsWith("<19>")) { DirCheck(Index, packets[i]); }
        else if (packets[i].StartsWith("<20>")) { PickItemCheck(Index); }
        else if (packets[i].StartsWith("<21>")) { DropItemCheck(Index, packets[i]); }
        else if (packets[i].StartsWith("<22>")) { ItemCheck(Index, packets[i]); }
        else if (packets[i].StartsWith("<23>")) { WeaponCheck(Index, packets[i]); }
        else if (packets[i].StartsWith("<24>")) { ArmorCheck(Index, packets[i]); }
    }
}
```

The server receives information such as:

```
<num>DATA\
```

My problem is, when I send a text like a "açai" to server, 
The server reads like this:

```
<num>açai
```

And when I send a text without ç

```
<num>text\
```

So, the send is in Ruby:

Command

```
@socket.send("<12>#{msg}\\")
```

Sender

```
  def send(data, flags = 0)
    result = Win32API.new('ws2_32', 'send', 'ppll', 'l').call(@descriptor, data, data.size, flags)
    result == -1 ? SocketError.check : result
  end
```

Because of this, I can not split the string , and it is with a very high length.

Anyone have tips or a solution?

Comment: give the code that send the data to the server, only got half of the picture right now

Comment: if you output, on the client side, data.size, does it give the proper size?

Comment: I thought about it , but could not find a command to get the size of the data on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this.

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[client.TCPClient.Available];
client.TCPClient.GetStream().Read(buffer, 0, client.TCPClient.Available);
```

Thank you.